# Rails: How to increment/ decrement a quantity column based on associated model events, without double counting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would appreciate some ideas and advice to help reconcile my model design with my business logic in a Rails 3.2 app.

I have a Product model, an Order model which has many Ordered_Products, and an Invoice model that has many Sold_Products.

In the Order form, the user sets details about the order, and then adds nested Ordered_Products, and their quantities.

The Invoice form operates in a similar way.

The Product model has a stock or quantity column, which records the total number of product items held.

I want the stock to change as orders and invoices are created, and I could do something like `after_create :decrement_product_stock` in the Sold_Products model, similar for Ordered_Products.

This is where the business logic comes into play. Orders are not fulfilled immediately. An order may be placed, and not delivered for some time. The stock should not be incremented until stock arrives.

So I could add a boolean order_fullfilled to the Orders form, and only run increment when order_fullfilled is true.

But then what if the user needs to go back into the Order form to make some edits. When they update the record, the increment method would be called again, this time in error?

Same would happen if the Invoice needed to be edited.

Has anyone tackled a similar issue? Can anyone offer advice on the issues I should be thinking about here? What would be the best way to handle this case?

Appreciate any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: If there's an action meant to `increment/decrement` the count `after_create` or `after_update`, have you considered using `dirty tracking` to check if attributes meant to trigger the increment have been changed?

Comment: thanks @daemonsy, I hadn't considered this, I wasn't aware of it, it's exactly what I need! thank you. But I'm having trouble implementing an initial basic test of this. In the OrderedProducts model, I have `after_update self.quantity.changed? ? self.product.increment!(:stock, self.quantity - self.quantity_was) : ""`. This is not running as expected. Actually I think the issue is that after_update is not being called, as if I try something like `after_update self.quantity = 100` this also doesn't work. Is after_update the correct callback to use? Thanks for your help!

Comment: should be `self.quantity_changed?` in my comment above. I can't edit for some reason

Comment: actually, on closer inspection this is working, but the updated value is not being saved to the database. In the console I get `UPDATE "products" SET "stock" = 1103, "updated_at" = '2012-03-04 10:37:24.074700' WHERE "products"."id" = 5`, where stock is modified as expected. But when I query the Products model, the value has not been updated. Any ideas how to debug why this is not being saved?

Comment: Glad it worked. Let me try to put it into a proper answer... =)

Comment: Anyway, on first cut, I think it should be `before_update`. By after update, it will be too late to increment the counter if it's the same record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andy, based on your question (sorry I'm a little confused), I think you have a field in your `OrderedProduct` that does `increment` and `decrement` of its product's stock based on whether the order has been fulfilled.

I think when the first instance the product order is made, you probably have to decide if you want to decrement the stock. If you do, might lose customers as some orders get abandoned but you eagerly decremented your stock. Vice versa, not decrementing after creating the `OrderedProduct` might lead to overselling.

Without knowing your case, I think you can do a `before_update` callback on your OrderedProduct. I've tried to use the code you posted to structure into what I think might work.

Let me know if it works for you. Personally, Im not so sure how `increment/decrement` methods  work. If they do, update my answer =)

```
class OrderedProduct < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_update :check_order_fulfilled

  def check_order_fulfilled
    if order_fulfilled_changed? 
      if order_fulfilled
        self.product.increment!(:stock, self.quantity - self.quantity_was)
      else
      #  self.product.decrement!  # Some incomplete logic, decrement if order_fulfilled                #set to false?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi daemonsy, thanks for your help. Logically, this is more or less what I want to achieve. However, the new product.stock value is not being written to the database. The correct PUT seems to be generated, e.g.`UPDATE "products" SET "stock" = 1153, "updated_at" = '2012-03-04 17:56:44.939112' WHERE "products"."id" = 5`, but then when I examine Product(5), the stock value has not been modified and remains at it's previous value (in this case, 4). I'm having trouble working out why this UPDATE is not being written. Would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: wow, after struggling with this for ages, it seems that the updated product.stock values are being written to the database. However, I am having to restart the console in order to see these changes. I'm not sure why this would be, or whether it has any implications for the app itself. I will play with this a little more, and then update my question to try to clarify things. Thanks daemonsy, I will be accepting your answer, just as soon as I get to grips with these database issues :)

Comment: Just in case,  you have to call `reload!` to reload code changes. If you reloaded the model, the `PUT` should be reflected. But, other than reload, you have to re-call the variable, such as `@product = Product.last` to refresh the data.

Comment: A little off topic, but I found this while doing my work. [State Machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine). I think it's suitable for your usage to keep track of order states.

Comment: hi daemonsy, sorry for the delay in responding, I;ve been trying to get this working. Dirty tracking seems to be the ideal solution, but I am running into a problem. I'm trying to run the logic to increment/decrement Product.quantity when OrderedProduct is saved. However, this logic is conditional on Order.fulfilled. Changed parent attributes do not seem to be available to a nested model, i.e. Order and OrderedProduct are defined on the same form, but `OrderedProduct.order.fulfilled_changed?` never returns true. Does this sound right, or is something else the problem here?